# Unable to set margin-top to menu div

Tags: css, html, alignment, margin

Why I cannot use `margin` for my `a` links in `div` with `id="menu"`.

I can use `margin-left` right but I cannot use `margin-top` or `bottom`. I want to move the text a bit to the top, because I think it is crushed a little on the bottom border.

Why does margin top and bottom not work? Any ideas?

Live page is here: http://www.woojoin.com

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goal, to move the entire bar, you can add the attribute 'position:absolute' to #menu, or to just move the text you can apply that attribute to #menufix. This is just an introductory idea of course.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this?

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm currently seeing on your site, adding `display: inline-block` should do the trick.

```
#menu a {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because it has no layout. Set `display:block`, or `display:inline-block`.